# GridSearchCV select best model by f1 score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

Trying to implement a subset of GridSearchCV with a progressbar, I performed a GridSearchCV exploration on an exploration-search-tree dictionary, and obtained a bunch of results.

Now, how can I select the model with the highest `f1_score` (weighted)?

Reading the docs, it's not entirely clear to me: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Extract of my code, and why I cannot make complete sense out of it (see the last comment):

```
#hyper-parameter-tuning with a progress-bar
xgb_model   =   xgb.XGBClassifier(  objective           =   'binary:logistic', 
                                    eval_metric         =   'mlogloss',
                                    use_label_encoder   =   False
                                )
grid_param  =   { 'max_depth' : [5,10,20]   }
results     =   []
for current_dict_combination in tqdm(ParameterGrid(grid_param)):
    #current_dict_combination is as {'max_depth':6} but GridSearchCV requires something as {'max_depth':[6]}
    unit_list_grid_param        =   my_function(current_dict_combination) #out of the scope. Just imagine how it works
    #now, unit_list_grid_param is as {'max_depth' : [6] }
    gsearch                     =   GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_model, param_grid=unit_list_grid_param , scoring='f1_weighted' , n_jobs=1 , cv=cv)
    gsearch.fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_test,y_pred               =   y_test,gsearch.predict(x_test)
    report                      =   classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
    results.append((gsearch.best_params_, gsearch.best_score_,report))

for i in results:
    i_best_params   =   i[0]
    i_best_score    =   i[1]
    i_report        =   i[2]
    
    print("------------------------")
    xgb_model_debug = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective           =   'binary:logistic', 
                                        eval_metric         =   'mlogloss',
                                        use_label_encoder   =   False
                                    )
    xgb_model_debug.set_params(**i_best_params)    
    print(str(i_best_params))
    print(str(i_best_score))
    print(str(i_report))
    xgb_model_debug.fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_pred              =   xgb_model_debug.predict(x_test)
    accuracy            =   accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
    f1_score_result     =   f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted', labels=np.unique(y_pred))
    #neither of these values matches the i_best_score, so, what is the i_best_score (GridSearchCV.best_score_)??
    print('xgb_model_debug-accuracy='+str(accuracy))
    print('xgb_model_debug-f1score ='+str(f1_score_result))
```

Comment: I know I'm using a, let's say, exotic use of GridSearchCV: instead of letting it iterate through the exploration-domain, I'm iterating it myself (just for printing a nice progressbar) and trying my best to choose the best result out of the exploration-domain